# Accidentally calling a scammer

Tags: phone, iphone, scam

Today and for the last couple of days, an unknown number from Melbourne (that is also NOT an unknown caller ID) has been consistently calling me on my iPhone. I've been constantly forgetting to block his number until today for some reason, my iPhone rang the number back.

To what I believed, I ignored the call (because I was busy doing something else). Then with the phone in my pocket, there was a missed call notification and when walking, the iPhone thought I swiped the notification which then rang the caller back. I didn't notice until 20 minutes later when it started playing some jingles. I hang up and immediately blocked the number, but I was worried about something.

I heard that if you ring some scam numbers, they are able to charge thousands of dollars. Can they do this to me? What should I do now? Call my telephone service provider?

Edit: I checked my call plan and it said it was unlimited, along with messaging. However, due to my lack of knowledge about my call plan and how phones work (since I'm not the one who set it up), I'm not sure If I'm safe, especially that I saw [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77088/can-my-phone-be-affected-by-malware-through-mobile-phone-signal?rq=1).

Comment: Can you check your balance to see how much you actually spent?

Comment: How would I do that on the iPhone? the mobile tab in settings?

Comment: It depends on your service provider, but usually you just need to call a number. Here are a few examples: [Vodafone](https://support.vodafone.co.uk/Account-billing-and-TopUps/How-you-receive-and-pay-your-bill/40246495/How-can-I-check-my-balance-since-my-last-bill.htm), [O2](http://www.o2.co.uk/help/pay-and-go/checking-your-balance), [Sprint](https://www.sprint.com/assets/includes/widgets/en/customer_service_flyer_en.pdf).

Comment: Ok I downloaded the service provider's app and it said my calls were unlimited. Could the scammer charge me in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a scammer can charge you differently and that will not be covered by the normal 'unlimited' plan you have subscription to.

But in most of the cases, those are special numbers that use other prefixes instead of the area code. You probably know that most 0-800-numbers are free and available in many countries. Well, just like that, the 0-900-number can be numbers with special tariff that will charge a few times the normal fee. Those are not covered by your subscription and will be charged separately.

Using a standard phone number in over-charge mode is also possible, but a lot harder to accomplish by a scammer.

Comment: I rang my service provider and they said nothing was charged. It was just a normal telephone-like number.

Comment: Lucky you then. :D